# Centering divs that positioned at the bottom of their container

Tags: html, css

I'm recording a video via webcam, and I've got a button `.videoMain` to start the record and a timer `#videoTimer` along with it. The `videoMain` is a class because after I start the recording, I change it into a button that stops the recording, and then after it stops, it becomes a playback button

```html
<div id="videoBox" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="videoTimer" style="position: absolute; display: inline-block; bottom: 0px;">
    <div aria-label="Countdown timer" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;">. 
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="ant-btn videoMain ant-btn-circle" style="position: absolute; display: inline-block; bottom: 0px; height: 67px; width: 67px; margin: 4px; z-index:1000;">
    <span>Start</span>
  </button>
  <div id="webcamOuter">
    <video autoplay="" playsinline="" style="width: 750px; height: 100%; margin: auto; border-radius: 10px;">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've positioned the button and the timer on top of each other, at the bottom of the `#videoBox`, however it's not centered and I can't figure out why. It's about 5% right of center. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks so much

Comment: Your code shows it 5% right of the left edge, not the center, btw. Is there code you have that's not included in the question?

Comment: I included all the position, display, size, and margin values for these divs. There's other divs on the page, but I left those out. Happy to add if helpful. Where is the 5% coming from? Is this the margin + the border of the button?

Comment: The 5% was just to borrow the approximation you used. Run the code snippet I've converted your question's code into to see what I mean.

Comment: My bad - so hard to get all the code from all these dependencies into the question. Clearly didn't give enough info, but the below answer will work for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy hard code fix is to add a margin left for 50% less half of your buttons width

```css
[type=button] {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 67px;
  width: 67px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 33.5px); 
  z-index:1000;
  
}
#videoBox {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
#webcamOuter {
  width: 750px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="videoBox" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="videoTimer">
    <div aria-label="Countdown timer" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;">. 
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="ant-btn videoMain ant-btn-circle" value="Start">
  <div id="webcamOuter">
    <video autoplay="" playsinline="">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```